# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string - Getting this error after using NativeBaseProvider

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I upgraded native-base library from `2.13.14` to `3.0.3` and wrapped my App.js content in `NativeBaseProvider`. Here is the error I got after doing this:

`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

--

My Code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {I18nManager, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {NativeBaseProvider, Container} from 'native-base';

import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';
import {PlayerContextProvider} from './contexts/PlayerContext';
import MainStackNavigator from './Navigators/MainStackNavigator';

const App = () => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(() => {
      console.log('player is setup');

      TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
        capabilities: [
          TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
          TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE,
          TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_STOP,
          TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_JUMP_BACKWARD,
          TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_JUMP_FORWARD,
        ],
        jumpInterval: 30,
      });
      setIsReady(true);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Container>
        {isReady ? (
          <PlayerContextProvider>
            <NavigationContainer>
              <MainStackNavigator />
            </NavigationContainer>
          </PlayerContextProvider>
        ) : (
          <Container>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </Container>
        )}
      </Container>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};

I18nManager.forceRTL(true);

export default App;
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem without any solution so far. I tried updating native-base from `2.15.2` to `3.0.0` or `3.2.1`, results in the same error.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem, find the answer below...

Answer (score 1):

I did found the root cause of this problem (in my case). The approach was to go down the navigator structure (in your case start with `MainStackNavigator`) and replace the rendered component with the example code from https://docs.nativebase.io/setup-provider until it breaks:

```
function Test() {
  return (
    <Box flex={1} bg="#fff" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

In my case it lead me to a component which was using deprecated `native-base` elements from v2. Sadly there is no good deprecation guide or migration guide which tells you how to upgrade from v2 to v3.

So following this approach might lead out of this situation (the error message is not really helpful). Keep an eye on the following deprecated components or functions and replace them as follows:

- `Header` -> use `HStack` [docs.nativebase.io/3.0.0/migration/Header](https://docs.nativebase.io/3.0.0/migration/Header)
- `Body` -> use `Box` or `Container` (not documented)
- `Left` -> use `Center` or remove (not documented)
- `Right` -> use `Center` or remove (not documented)
- `getTheme` -> use `extendTheme` [docs.nativebase.io/setup-provider#add-custom-theme-optional](https://docs.nativebase.io/setup-provider#add-custom-theme-optional)
- `StyleProvider` -> use `NativeBaseProvider` [docs.nativebase.io/setup-provider](https://docs.nativebase.io/setup-provider)

This is my list of deprecated components so far. In addition here are some update guides for

- Icon [docs.nativebase.io/3.0.0/migration/Icon](https://docs.nativebase.io/3.0.0/migration/Icon)
- Button [docs.nativebase.io/3.0.0/migration/Button](https://docs.nativebase.io/3.0.0/migration/Button)

and there are a lot more to be found on this index page https://docs.nativebase.io/3.0.0/migration/

I hope It helps you solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to move the forceRTL method inside the useEffect of the app initialization.

like :

```
useEffect(() => {
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);    // here..
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(() => {
```

Might it will help you.

Comment: It didn't work @Jignesh. Error is related to the Component. When I replace code inside NativeBaseProvider it works fine with simple <Text> Hello </Text>

Comment: Okay, I got it your problem. There must be an issue with the imports that you have added in the above file please have a close check of all of them.