# Issue while migrating from NativeBase v2 to v3

Tags: react-native, native-base

Is the migration from v2 to v3 working? Apparently, a lot of tests broke when I did the migration but the core error is saying that I should have nativebaseprovider in jest, I am not sure why is that needed when I'm running the test in isolation?

Comment: I had issues while migrating too, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653362/9915210

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing a component that uses a NativeBase component, you'll need to wrap the test's render using NativeBaseProvider because each NB component needs a theme from Provider's context. Also, you can create a custom render function that wraps the passed JSX in NativeBaseProvider.